# Addition on HashSet of KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, key-value, hashset, sortedset

I have a list of entries. Each entry contains a string and a numerical value. The same string  can appear one or more times in a list and it can have a different numerical value. be I am looking for an elegant way to process the list. The end result should be a list of unique pairs of string and (sum of values for the string). Each unique string should be associated with the sum of all numerical values for the string. I consider creating a HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, double>> and to add each string to the HashSet. But I am not sure how to add all values together in a single loop. The code below works, but it is inefficient.

```
        SortedSet<string> symbols = new SortedSet<string>();
        HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, double>> results = new HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();
        string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
        
        foreach(string line in lines) {
            string[] values = line.Split('\t');
            string symbol = values[0].Trim();
            symbols.Add(symbol);
        }
        
        foreach(string uniqueSymbol in symbols) {
            double value = 0;
            foreach(string line in lines) {
                string[] values = line.Split('\t');
                string symbol = values[0].Trim();
                string sProfit = values[7].Trim();
                double fProfit = Convert.ToDouble(sProfit);
                
                if(symbol == uniqueSymbol) {
                    value += fProfit;
                }
            }
            
            results.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>(uniqueSymbol, value));
        }
```

Comment: You _say_ you need a set of pairs, but one of those values in the pair must be unique (i.e. a _key_) and the other does not need to be unique but must be linked to the key. You're describing a dictionary. Use a dictionary.

Comment: There is little advantage to using `KeyValuePair<>` as a hash-collection key type compared to `ValueTuple`, which overrides  `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` to perform much better for that role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several others here, I agree that a `Dictionary` sounds like what suits your needs best. If using Linq is an option, here is an apporach that should work:

```
Dictionary<string, double> results = lines
    .Select(line => line.Split('\t'))
    .Select(lineEntries => (
        Symbol: lineEntries[0].Trim(), 
        Value: Convert.ToDouble(lineEntries[7].Trim()))) // Some validation should be done here
    .GroupBy(symbolAndValue => symbolAndValue.Symbol)
    .ToDictionary(
        gr => gr.Key,
        gr => gr.Select(symbolAndValue => symbolAndValue.Value).Sum());
```

I'm creating a tuple `(string Symbol, double Value)` for each `line`, then grouping them by `Symbol`, then creating a dictionary using `Symbol` as the `Key` and the sum of values connected to `Symbol` as the `Value` for each dictionary entry.

---

A slightly more concise approach would be merging the two `Select` statements together by performing `line.Split('\t')` twice:

```
.Select(line => (
    Symbol: line.Split('\t')[0].Trim(), 
    Value: Convert.ToDouble(line.Split('\t')[7].Trim())))
```

Comment: I voted your proposed solution because it was the first I tried and it worked  without any changes and it is pretty concise. My thanks to all others who posted solutions before and I apologise for not having selected their solution.

Comment: @Nick_F Great, I am glad it was helpful! Check out the added suggestion as well.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure why you need a to be using a `HashSet` for something that certainly *looks* the a job for a `Dictionary`.

Here’s how I would approach populating such a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, double> result = new Dictionary<string, double>();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] values = line.Split(“\t”);
    string symbol = values[0].Trim();
    double profit = Convert.ToDouble(values[7].Trim());
    result.TryGetValue(symbol, out double _profit);
    result[symbol] = _profit + profit;
}
```

If you needed to extract those into a `HashSet` that should be easy enough.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I will try it shortly. I thought about using a Dictionary, but I didn't see the advantage of it :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand that you want to get the sum of the duplicate row values, this might be helpful.

```
Dictionary<string, double> results = new Dictionary<string, double>();
foreach(string line in lines) {
            string[] values = line.Split('\t');
            string symbol = values[0].Trim();
            double profit = Convert.ToDouble(values[7].Trim());
            results.Add(symbol, profit);
}

List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> grouped = (from kvp in results 
                                             group kvp by kvp.Key
                                             into g
                                             select
                                             new KeyValuePair<string, double> 
                                             (g.Key,g.Sum(e => e.Value))) 
.ToList();
```

Comment: This will throw an `ArgumentException` on `results.Add(symbol, profit);`, given that there will be multiple duplicates of symbol.